# Is there a regular expression for "foldernameMM_DD__YYYY"

Tags: regex, perl

I am setting up Perl script that runs periodically and delete unwanted folders and to identity auto generated folder my organization following naming convention like

> foldernameMM_DD_YYYY

can someone please help me with this regex

Comment: Please share your code what you tried so far.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$foldername = "abc";
if ($folder =~ m/^\Q$foldername\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{4}$/) {
  rmdir $folder; // `rmdir` works if folder is empty; otherwise you could `use File::Path 'rmtree'`;
}
```

*Note: Be warned that this regexp accepts invalid dates too (i.e.: **99_88_0000**), but this should not be an issue for your use case... It is not easy at all to make a regexp to accept valid dates... It not even feasible to match leap years, for example, with a simple regexp...*

Comment: Please accept the answer that best answered your question...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your are looking for a date, followed by a string literal "foldername", an inaccurate version would be:

```
/foldername[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/
```

It's inaccurate because it would match something like "foldername98_76_5432". However, it's a start and you could at least start perfecting it.